# How to define deep learning?

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, ne.neural-evol

Ive read some articles about deep learning but I found its hard to provide a clear definition of deep learning.

For me its like an intelligent feature selection method.

But it seems that its not precise enough.

Comment: Some ideas: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/86800/12359